# Ruby on Rails - Duplicate Records with Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

On my checkout page, I am loading a form that has two addresses. One for billing and another for shipping. I have these setup as nested attributes of my cart object. When the user creates/updates their addresses the code in my controller action is executed like so:

```
def update_addresses

    @countries = Country.all
    @states = State.all 
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:cart][:id])   
    if params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:address_type] == "Billing" && params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["1"][:address_type] == "Shipping"

      bla = @cart.cart_addresses.find_by(address_type: "Billing")
      spa = @cart.cart_addresses.find_by(address_type: "Shipping")
      if (params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:id].blank?) && !(bla.blank?)
        params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:id] = bla.id
      end

      if (params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["1"][:id].blank?) && !(spa.blank?)
        params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["1"][:id] = spa.id
      end

        @cart.update(params.require(:cart).permit(cart_addresses_attributes: [:id, :address_type, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone, :address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city, :zip_code, :country, :state]))


    #more code to render response here

end
```

Upon update, the browser posts the form data with an id attribute and all works fine. Upon create, the browser posts the form data without the id and the address records are created.

I've had a couple of instances where a user opened up 2 browser windows on my checkout page before they had created addresses, after they created the addresses the first time, the user went back to the page where they had not created the addresses. This second page still has the form for creating the records (not updating the ones that were previously created. This results in 2 shipping addresses and 2 billing addresses which is wrong.

So, I added in these lines of code to check for this case and set the id param to the previously created id if one already existed.

```
bla = @cart.cart_addresses.find_by(address_type: "Billing")
  spa = @cart.cart_addresses.find_by(address_type: "Shipping")
  if (params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:id].blank?) && !(bla.blank?)
    params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:id] = bla.id
  end

  if (params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["1"][:id].blank?) && !(spa.blank?)
    params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["1"][:id] = spa.id
  end
```

This works just fine, but as you can see I keep having to hard code in the param values in my code. To me it seems like this is a bad approach but I don't know how else to check the parameters and alter then if needed. I've done some searching but nothing I've seen has really pointed me in any direction.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your database schema looks complicated. You should follow some rules to create schema and also you must use associations to make this bit easy.

Comment: have you looked at `accepts_nested-attriutes_for`? especially the section in the Rails Guides on Complex Forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms